# Stretch a div to fit gap

Tags: html, css

I have a layout like this:

```
+---------------------------------+
| #container                      |
|+-------------------------------+|
|| #top                          ||
|| This changes height           ||
||                  dynamically  ||
|+-------------------------------+|
|+-------------------------------+|
|| #mid                          ||
||                               ||
|| This changes height           ||
||                 dynamically   ||
|+-------------------------------+|
|                                 |
|                                 |
|                                 |
|                                 |
|                                 |
|+-------------------------------+|
|| #bot                          ||
||       This has fixed height   ||
||                               ||
|+-------------------------------+|
+---------------------------------+
```

When **top** or **mid** is enlarged, they overflow from the **container**. How can I make it so they don't go past **bot** ? When they want to overflow, a scrollbar should appear for the inner divs ( aka. overflow auto)

CSS

```
#container{
    position: absolute;
} //Container's container has position:relative.
#bot{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Should `#container` stretch or should one or more of the inner divs become a scrollbar?

Comment: @LinkinTED Yes, I had forgot to mention that. I updated the question.

Comment: Scrollbar on the #container div? Or the inner div?

Comment: add `overflow:scroll` property in css of #top and #mid

Comment: @LinkinTED Inner divs. Updated the question again

Comment: `min-height` at `#bot`'s height for `#container` would be enough

Comment: Could you post your full CSS?

Comment: I *think* what you'll want (AIUI) is for `#top` and `#mid` to be `position: relative;` and `#mid` to have a bottom margin a little higher than the height of `#bot` so that it leaves a space for it. You'll probably also want a `max-height` on `#container` and `overflow: auto;` on `#mid` - that *should* set a maximum height that can be utilised by `#mid` being effectively `#container` - `#top.height` - `#bottom.height` with overflow becomming a scroll bar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a `#parent` div and set its `max-height` to be `screen height - #bot height`, set `overflow` to be `scroll`.

HTML:

```
+---------------------------------+
| #container                      |
|+-------------------------------+|
|| #parent                       ||
||+-----------------------------+||
||| #top                        |||
||| This changes height         |||
|||                  dynamically|||
||+-----------------------------+||
||+-----------------------------+||
||| #mid                        |||
|||                             |||
||| This changes height         |||
|||                 dynamically |||
||+-----------------------------+||
|+-------------------------------+|
|                                 |
|                                 |
|                                 |
|                                 |
|                                 |
|+-------------------------------+|
|| #bot                          ||
||       This has fixed height   ||
||                               ||
|+-------------------------------+|
+---------------------------------+
```

Comment: Ah, I have just thought the same. I will try and update you with the result. It should work, though

Comment: Can you suggest anything for how to make #top visible at all times? If #mid gets large enough, I will scroll bottom and not be able to see #top then.

Comment: assuming `#top` is a header - make it `position: fixed;` and add a `margin-top` to `#mid` equal to the height of `#top`... you will have a problem with the dynamic height of `#top` though as you'll not know how large to make that margin - if you could fix the height of `#top` it would make life easier.

Comment: Yeah, it's not really a header, it is contacts list for a chat application, and mid is the chat messages. You can guess what bot is :) I wanted the contact-list visible too, at all times, but I guess I'm gonna have to carry to a separate column or something

Comment: @aec Heh - I'd be tempted to go all JavaScripty - you could do a lot with jQueryUI and 'Draggable' : http://jqueryui.com/draggable/ ... good luck ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `height` and `width` to a set amount for them both. Also, the `overflow:` should be set to `scroll`.

Comment: Their content changes real time. I'm looking for a non-javascript solution if I can find one. So hardcoding the height is not desirable atm.

Comment: @TJonS `overflow: scroll;` is the same as `overflow: auto;` as mentioned in the original question - except `auto` will only display the scrollbars when needed NOT all the time (as per `overflow: scroll'`) so I think it's safe to assume that it's been covered, yes?